# Convert zpl data to imagem with PHP

Tags: php, zpl

There is any way to convert `zpl` data into an image with PHP?

I know the labelary.com service, but I need to do this without this web service.

In my search, I found one way to transform the image into `zpl` data, but I need the inverse.

Well, I'm a PHP developer but if you have any solution in another language, let me know.

Comment: Why not use their API? http://labelary.com/service.html

Comment: High volume and request limit =/